# How to use firebase push notification in react native expo after eject

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

I've created an expo project and eject that project and now I've to use notifications but I'm getting this error...

```
index.bundle?platfor…&minify=false:38768 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId;
Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId;
```

Comment: Use this https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage

Comment: I've also tried this but still I'm not getting any fcm token

Comment: Can you show us the code? To help you

Comment: And also did you do this setup https://rnfirebase.io/? you are using expo bare so you need to do this setup yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Firebase notification depends on the native module which is not an option for Expo App :

Some solutions you can try:

1. Expo provides a free cloud notification service, does not have infrastructure like Firebase but you can build a small web app to trigger a notification for promotion, marketing or another specific purpose.
2. Apart from Expo SDK 42, Expo support custom development client, you can build your custom version of Expo Go with `react-native-firebase` pre-build and use any Firebase service you need.